# How can i filter values from column with checkboxes

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

Now what I need is, when I click on the checkbox dtGone, list need to filter for me all records with 74 value, or when I click another one need to show me all records with value 5.

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string filterstatus = "";
        if (dtGone.Checked)
        {
            if (dtStay.Checked)
            {
                filterstatus = "'74' ,";
            }
            else
            {
                filterstatus = "'74'";
            }
        }

        if (dtStay.Checked)
        {
            if (dtGone.Checked)
            {
                filterstatus = "'5' ,";
            }
            else
            {
                filterstatus = "'5'";
            }
        }

        using (SqlConnection db = new
             SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString))
        {
            if (db.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                db.Open();
            string query = "select something, id, idstatus, desc " +
                            " from table" +
                           $" where idstatus in (" + filterstatus + ")";
        }
    }
}
```

When I click the button to filter for me records they show me the following error:

> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

**Here is the my aspx:**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="form-group">
        <asp:Button ID="button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="button1_Click1" />

        <asp:CheckBox ID="dtGone" runat="server" />
        <asp:CheckBox ID="dtStay" runat="server" />

        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
            <Columns
                <asp:BoundField DataField="something" HeaderText="barcode" SortExpression="barcode" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="idstatus" SortExpression="idstatus" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="idstatus" HeaderText="description" SortExpression="description" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="desc" HeaderText="idtype" SortExpression="idtype" />

            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:_cl1_nlbConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [something], [id], [idtstatus], [desc] FROM [table]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Did you debug the code? You can use `try...catch` to catch exception and see what is the error...

Comment: when `dtStay.Checked` is true `filterstatus` will have value `"'74' ,"` This is not a correct value for `IN` query. You need to debug your code to see what exact error you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

Let's *extract method*:

```
  private static IEnumerable<int> InValues() {
    yield return -1; // dummy value; we don't want to have syntax error for "idstatus in ()"

    if (dtGone.Checked)
      yield return 74;

    if (dtStay.Checked)
      yield return 5;
  }
```

Then you can easily build the query:

```
 string query =  
   $@"select something, 
             id, 
             idstatus, 
             desc    -- desc may appear to be a reserved word which you should escape
        from table   -- table may appear to be a reserved word which you should escape
       where idstatus in ({string.Join(", ", InValues())})";
```

If *one and only one* of `dtGone` and `dtStay` can be checked, you can simplify the code:

```
 string query =  
   $@"select something, 
             id, 
             idstatus, 
             desc    -- desc may appear to be a reserved word which you should escape
        from table   -- table may appear to be a reserved word which you should escape
       where idstatus = {(dtGone.Checked ? 74 : 5)}";
```